# Conditional conditions in a loop

Tags: java, conditional-statements

Is it possible to use different conditions for a loop depending on another condition?

For example

```
boolean isDfa = true;
```

if `isDfa` is `true`, I want the condition of a while loop to be:

```
while(!s.hasAllTransitions())
```

and otherwise, if `isDfa` is `false`, I want the condition of the while loop to be:

```
while(!input.equals("next"))
```

Is using two separate loops the only way to achieve this?

Comment: while((isDfa && !s.hasAllTransitions()) || !input.equals("next")) should do it

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can combine the conditions :

```
while((isDfa && !s.hasAllTransitions()) || (!isDfa && !input.equals("next"))) {

}
```

Comment: @clcto Yep, I just noticed that myself :)

Comment: Thanks! Think I was over-complicating this in my head!

Answer (score 1):

You can use the following condition:

```
while((isDfa && !s.hasAllTransitions()) || (!isDfa && !input.equals("next"))) {

}
```

Answer (score 1):

Another way to do this:

```
if (isDfa) {
    while(!s.hasAllTransitions()) {

    }
}
else {
    while(!input.equals("next")) {

    }
}
```

Comment: This answer has a typo, but the bigger problem is that it involves duplicating the body of the loop.

Comment: @ajb- That can be avoided by creating a method and calling that method from the while loops.

Answer (score 1):

You can switch the while condition on the fly with a ternary operator

```
while(isDfa? !s.hasAllTransitions() : !input.equals("next")) {
  //do stuff
}
```

This is saying: if isDfa is true and s.hasAllTransitions is false, then continue. But, if isDfa is false and input is not equal to next, then continue.

Answer (score 1):

You could use the ternary operator:

```
while ((isDfa) ? !s.hasAllTransitions() : !input.equals("next")) {
    ...
}
```

But sometimes, instead of trying to cram everything into one complex condition, it's best to break things up.  Consider doing it this way:

```
while (true) {
    if (isDfa) {
        if (s.hasAllTransitions()) {
            break;
        }
    } else {
        if (input.equals("next")) {
            break;
        }
    }
    ...
}
```

or

```
while (true) {
    boolean done;
    if (isDfa) {
        done = s.hasAllTransitions();
    } else {
        done = input.equals("next");
    }
    if (done) {
        break;
    }
    ...
}
```

Comment: Why use nested if's here that is not as readable as one if else and set a boolean based on what is correct.

Comment: @brso05 Yes, a `boolean` could be used, if you follow it with something like `if (theBoolean) break;`.  Which one is more readable is in the eye of the beholder.

Comment: don't need to use break use boolean in while condition.

Comment: If the code to determine the value of the `boolean` has to be done every time in the loop, and it needs to be done at the beginning of the loop, it's hard to put the `boolean` into the `while` condition without some code duplication.  In this case using `break` is simplest.

Answer (score 0):

You could do something like this:

```
boolean testBoolean = false;
while(!testBoolean)
{
   if(isDfa)
   {
       testBoolean = s.hasAllTransitions();
   }
   else
   {
       testBoolean = input.equals("next");
   }
}
```

Comment: This loop will execute 0 times.  Even if you change the initial value of `testBoolean` to `false`, it's still not quite an answer to the question, because now you've created a loop that will always execute at least once, while the OP's loop does not have that property.

Comment: You still haven't solved the second problem I pointed out.  Please remember that the loop in the original question probably has some statements in it.

Comment: @ajb there is no problem he can change testBoolean to true before the loop if it isn't suppose to execute or he can use a do while loop.  Never once did he say that the loop may not execute atleast once.

Comment: Huh?  He gave a condition that could be true or false as soon as the loop starts.  That means it's possible that the loop body will never execute.  That means that any solution that causes the loop body to execute at least once _in all cases_, without testing the condition beforehand, is incorrect.  Doing the test to set up `testBoolean` before the loop will work but involves duplicated code.

Comment: @ajb Huh??? Not if the condition is always true the first iteration I don't know what he is doing with his code and neither do you.